# Want to add event to calender in Android

Tags: android, events, insert, calendar

HI I am developing a android app in which I am suppose to handle calendar . I am unable to add event in my own calendar . I have used following code . using that code I am able to add event in a default calendar .. please suggest me the changes needed in my code to add event in the calendar of my app

```
private void addevent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        calIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My House Party");
        calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "My Beach House");
        calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "A Pig Roast on the Beach");
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 4, 16);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true);
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
             calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
             calDate.getTimeInMillis());
        startActivity(calIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "event added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

if add event in calender use below code , that work in my calender.

// this code for add event in calender.

```
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, Events.ALL_DAY_VALUE);
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, startTimeInMilli);
    values.put(Events.DTEND, endTimeInMilli);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, strTaskName);
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, strDescription);
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, 0);
    values.put(Events.VISIBILITY, Events.VISIBILITY_VALUE);

    Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase(this) + "events");
    Uri uri = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

// this function call upper code.

```
 private String getCalendarUriBase(Activity act) {

    String calendarUriBase = null;
    Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
    Cursor managedCursor = null;
    try {
        managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
    } else {
        calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        try {
            managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null,
                    null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (managedCursor != null) {
            calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
        }
    }
    return calendarUriBase;
}
```

// other static class for event constants.

```
 public class Events {

public static String ALL_DAY = "allDay";
public static String DTSTART = "dtstart";
public static String DTEND = "dtend";
public static String TITLE = "title";
public static String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static String CALENDAR_ID = "calendar_id";
public static String EVENT_TIMEZONE = "eventTimezone";

public static String VISIBILITY = "visibility";
public static String HASALARM = "hasAlarm";

public static int VISIBILITY_VALUE = 0;
public static int HASALARM_VALUE = 1;
public static int ALL_DAY_VALUE = 0;

}
```

Comment: managedQuery() is a deprecated function n giving error there can u please mention some changes over there

Comment: which error comes ??.

in my code no error on managedQuery() function , i set minSdkVersion="7" and tested galaxy s its work perfectly. and add event in calender.

Comment: its giving force close while adding event n showing exception at managedCursor = act.managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null,
                    null);

Answer (score 0):

You need to **pass calendar id** of your app in your intent putExtra.

```
calIntent.putExtra(Events.CALENDAR_ID , my_cal_id);
```

To get list of all available calendar in your device you can use following code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT 
                       >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1)
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI,new String[] 
          { Calendars._ID, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME }, null ,null, null);
else
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar
    /calendars"),new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, "selected=1",null, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {

                calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                System.out.println(""+cursor.getInt(0) + " -- "+ 
                                                           cursor.getString(1));
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
```