# Adding events to my own calender in Android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have been creating an event calender with the code from the following link http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

But this only creates the Calendar, not allowing users to add events. I have also checked this link [Want to add event to calender in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012476/want-to-add-event-to-calender-in-android) 
where it is defined that how to add events in my own calender(NOT default calender). But I cannot  understand how to implement this portion in my code. Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.